# Strange behaviour in Expandablelistview - Android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, settext

Im trying to implement an activity that uses ExpandableListView and I have gotten so far but now I have found some strange behavior.

My activity is meant to record food intake as specified by the user. they have a choice of menus (breakfast, lunch and dinner - the outer group) which expand to show their contents.
when a user clicks on an inner menu item a dialog appears asking them for the qty. once they enter a qty and dismiss the dialog the text on the menu item changes to reflect the quantity of that item that has  been consumed
[image: fig 1]

The above image shows the list in a closed state.

below is the list after I have opened the lunch menu and clicked on 'Potato Chips' and indicating a Quantity of 1. As you can see the 'Potato' itemtext has now been changed to reflect the Qty of 1.

[image: fig 2]

The strange part happens now. if I click on 'Lunch' and close the list and then click on it again re-opening it, the 'Qty X 1' text has jumped to another item (Milk)

[image]

each time I open and close the list it jumps back and forth between the two items. Also if I open up other items, such as breakfast, I find that they too have now gotten items with 'Qty X 1' even though I havent clicked them.

The bits of code that are relevant are as such:

The XML for a child element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="50dip"

         android:textSize="14dip"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="200dip"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
         android:layout_height="40dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/qty_display"
         android:text="-"
         android:textSize="14dip"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code thats triggered on clicking a child element:

```
public boolean onChildClick(
            ExpandableListView parent, 
            View v, 
            int groupPosition,
            int childPosition,
            long id) {

           // open the dialog and inflate the buttons
     myDialog  = new Dialog(this);
  myDialog.setTitle("Food Item Qty");
  myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.food_intake_dialog);
  final Button ok = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.fi_ok_but);
     Button cancel = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.fi_cancel_but); 

     //the id for this item is stored as a hash key in a map (say, item_id01)
     String key = "item_id"+groupPosition+""+childPosition;
     current_selected_food_item_id = Integer.parseInt(itemMap.get(key));

       // inflate the textview that shows the qty for this item on the expandablelist
     barQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qty_display);

        // set the ok button to record teh quantity on press
     ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View viewParam) {

                             //inflate the input box that receives quantity from user
    EditText fiQty = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.fiQty);
    // get the quantity and append the text on hte list item
    String qty = fiQty.getText().toString();
    barQty.setText("Qty X "+qty);

                            //open the database and save state 
                FoodIntake.this.application.getFoodIntakeHelper().open();   
 FoodIntake.this.application.getFoodIntakeHelper().storeFoodIntakeLog(current_selected_food_item_id,qty,visit_id,remote_visit_id);
    String log = FoodIntake.this.application.getFoodIntakeHelper().getFoodIntakeLog(visit_id);
    FoodIntake.this.application.getFoodIntakeHelper().close();

                        //    append the main food intake list and close the dialog
                            list.setText("Food Intake Log:\n\n"+log);
    myDialog.cancel();
   }
     });
```

The above code opens a dialog, accepts a value for quantity, appends the list element to reflect this, also saves to database and sets a textview with the selected item and quantity.

Sorry to just dump a whole load of code, but this has me stumped and hopefully someone can help.

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the dialogs. I had the same problem in my project and couldn't fix it. I think the `ExpandableListView` has a bug when opening children. I had only one child per group and when I expand a group, the child moves to another group. After testing, I found out that when I expand the children are reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Android reuses dialogs. So the behavior you are seeing could be a result of that. You could use a activity managed dialog and use [onPrepareDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to update dialog contents.

Comment: When you say that android reuses dialogs, do you mean the list elements? or do you mean the actual dialog that is used to enter the quantity of an item?

Thanks