# how to get id of check boxes in expanded list view item?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have an expanded list view that have check boxes in parent nodes as well as child items.
all data comes from web service so its dynamic.

Image attached:

[image]

Now on menu item click i want to fetch all check box status .
please guide me how can i get id of check boxes used in it.

code attached:

```
/**
 * 
 */


    public class Object_SecurityActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onContentChanged() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onContentChanged();
        }

        private AndroidClientEntity obj_android_client;
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox2";
        private String username, password, clientname;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            //setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Intent security_intent = getIntent();
            String id = security_intent.getStringExtra("id");
            obj_android_client = (AndroidClientEntity) getApplicationContext();
            username = obj_android_client.getUsername();
            password = obj_android_client.getPassword();
            clientname = obj_android_client.getClientName();
            new Securityasync().execute(username, password, clientname, id);

        }

        class Securityasync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            String sesurity_response = null;
            ProgressDialog dialog;
            private Expandable_list_Adapter expListAdapter;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                if ((isOnline(Object_SecurityActivity.this).equals("true"))) {
                    Security_service security_obj = new Security_service();
                    try {
                        sesurity_response = security_obj.getUsersRoles(params[0],
                                params[1], params[2], params[3]);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (isOnline(Object_SecurityActivity.this).equals("true")) {

                    setContentView(R.layout.layout_expandable_listview);
                    ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> sub = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                    ArrayList<String> sub_id = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> objrid = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try {
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sesurity_response);
                        // JSONArray json_child=new JSONArray(sesurity_response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (json_obj.getString("PRid").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                                String ObjectRid = json_obj.getString("ObjectRid");
                                int m=0;
                                objrid.add(m,ObjectRid);
                                m++;
                                groupNames.add(json_obj.getString("Name"));
                                for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject json_child = json.getJSONObject(j);
                                    if (ObjectRid.equalsIgnoreCase(json_child
                                            .getString("PRid"))) {
                                        int n=0;
                                        sub_id.add(n,json_child.getString("ObjectRid"));
                                        sub.add(json_child.getString("Name"));
                                    }

                                }
                                child.add(sub);

                            }

                        }
                        expListAdapter = new Expandable_list_Adapter(getBaseContext(),
                                groupNames, child);
                        setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
                        Log.e("size in error", "son " + json.length());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("", "", e);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "parsing error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Log.e("sizeof list", ""+sub_id.size());
                    Iterator itr=objrid.iterator();


                    while(itr.hasNext()){
                        Log.e("id","value "+itr.next());
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }
        }

    }
```

And adapter class:

```
public class Expandable_list_Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> groupNames;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Expandable_list_Adapter(Context context, 
                        ArrayList<String> groupNames,
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child ) { 
        this.context = context;
        this.groupNames= groupNames;
        this.child = child;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024+childPosition );  // Max 1024 children per group
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
       String c = (String)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
        TextView color = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( color != null )
            color.setText( c );

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );

        //cb.setChecked(false);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child.get( groupPosition ).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupNames.get( groupPosition );        
    }

    public int getGroupCount(){
         return groupNames.size();
    }
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024 );  // To be consistent with getChildId
    } 

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false); 
        String gt = (String)getGroup( groupPosition );
        TextView colorGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( gt != null )
            colorGroup.setText( gt );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check2 );
        cb.setChecked(false);
        return v;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.e("is group checked","group "+groupPosition);
        Log.e("selectable","has" +childPosition);
        return true;
    } 

    public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {}
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
public void isChecked(){

}

}
```

Child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="#21415A"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

parent.xml is same as child.

please guide me how can i get ids of check boxes because on menu item selected i have to do operation basics on that.

Edit: i tried to setTag() and getTag() . but now expandable list view is showing strange behavior. when i select an checkbox and expand another group all chekbok boxes is set to default.
What i have to do in this case. i dont know the resion why it is not saving state. 
i am faceing same problem as [Strange behaviour in Expandablelistview - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633823/strange-behaviour-in-expandablelistview-android)
Plz guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally solved my problem.
Adapter class:

```
 public class Expandable_list_Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> groupNames;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Expandable_list_Adapter(Context context, 
                        ArrayList<String> groupNames,
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child ) { 
        AndroidClientEntity.objHasmap.clear();
        this.context = context;
        this.groupNames= groupNames;
        this.child = child;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024+childPosition );  // Max 1024 children per group
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
             v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
       String c = (String)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
       Log.e("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",c);

        TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( label != null )
            label.setText( c );

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1);
        //cb.setId(childPosition);
        cb.setTag(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition);
        cb.setChecked(false);
        if(AndroidClientEntity.objHasmap.get(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition)!=null)
        {
        cb.setChecked(AndroidClientEntity.objHasmap.get(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition));
        }
    //    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child.get( groupPosition ).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

        return groupNames.get( groupPosition );        
    }

    public int getGroupCount(){
         return groupNames.size();
    }
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024 );  // To be consistent with getChildId
    } 

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false); 
        String gt = (String)getGroup( groupPosition );
        TextView colorGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( gt != null )
            colorGroup.setText( gt );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check2 );
        cb.setTag(groupPosition+"cbgroup");
        //Object_SecurityActivityobjHasmap.put(groupPosition+"cbgroup", false);
        cb.setChecked(false);
        return v;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.e("is group checked","group "+groupPosition);
        Log.e("selectable","has" +childPosition);
        return true;
    } 

    public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {}
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }
public void isChecked(){

}

}
```

And Activity class:

```
public class Object_SecurityActivity extends ExpandableListActivity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) v.findViewWithTag(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition);
//Boolean state=objHasmap.get(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition);
    cb.toggle();
    if(cb.isChecked())
    {
        AndroidClientEntity.objHasmap.put(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition,true );

    }else
    {AndroidClientEntity.objHasmap.remove(groupPosition+"child"+childPosition);

    }

    //add value in set
//cb.setEnabled(state);
    return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
}



private AndroidClientEntity obj_android_client;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox2";
private String username, password, clientname;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent security_intent = getIntent();
    String id = security_intent.getStringExtra("id");

    obj_android_client = (AndroidClientEntity) getApplicationContext();
    username = obj_android_client.getUsername();
    password = obj_android_client.getPassword();
    clientname = obj_android_client.getClientName();
    new Securityasync().execute(username, password, clientname, id);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.context_menu_security,
            menu);
    return (super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // startDownload();
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.setsecurity) {
        //code here 
        Log.e("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","scejkkl yu menu pressed");
         }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
class Securityasync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String sesurity_response = null;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Expandable_list_Adapter expListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if ((isOnline(Object_SecurityActivity.this).equals("true"))) {
            Security_service security_obj = new Security_service();
            try {
                sesurity_response = security_obj.getUsersRoles(params[0],
                        params[1], params[2], params[3]);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (isOnline(Object_SecurityActivity.this).equals("true")) {

            setContentView(R.layout.layout_expandable_listview);
            ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> sub = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> child = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            ArrayList<String> sub_id = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> objrid = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sesurity_response);
                // JSONArray json_child=new JSONArray(sesurity_response);
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (json_obj.getString("PRid").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                        String ObjectRid = json_obj.getString("ObjectRid");
                        int m=0;
                        objrid.add(m,ObjectRid);
                        m++;
                        groupNames.add(json_obj.getString("Name"));
                        for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject json_child = json.getJSONObject(j);
                            if (ObjectRid.equalsIgnoreCase(json_child
                                    .getString("PRid"))) {
                                int n=0;
                                sub_id.add(n,json_child.getString("ObjectRid"));
                                sub.add(json_child.getString("Name"));
                            }

                        }
                        child.add(sub);

                    }

                }
                expListAdapter = new Expandable_list_Adapter(getBaseContext(),
                        groupNames, child);
                setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
                Log.e("size in error", "son " + json.length());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("", "", e);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "parsing error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Log.e("sizeof list", ""+sub_id.size());
            Iterator itr=objrid.iterator();


            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Log.e("id","value "+itr.next());
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Thanks to pallavi,amit rai and Photon.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what ever control you add on list or grid which are copied at run time have same id as you declare for one at the time of design

for eg : in you case these are childname,rgb,check1

so if you need to know about which checkbox uniquely 
you should go for one by one using for loop

and if you want to do some thing why don't you do this

on check box click event

```
public void onClickevent(View v)
{
private CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(v.getId());
    if (ch.IsChecked){
    //do some thing
     }
}
```

or alternatively you should go with my 
way add a unique field like

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtComp1_ID"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:textSize="1pt" >
    </TextView>
```

as it has zero width so it is not visible but it holds id of that row

now run a for loop for all item in list view

findview you check box and then find its parent and then again its child(text view) that this id field 
so now you have id and check box check status as previous 
this way you can get this

See example

```
v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearNotebookList);
            TextView _id, ID, Name;
            for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
                v = (LinearLayout) NotebookList.getAdapter().getView(i, null,
                        null);
                _id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Notebook_ID);

                Available = (CheckBox) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookAvailable);
                Display = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookDisplay);
                Demo = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookDemo);
                str_id = (String) _id.getText();

                if (Available.isChecked()) {
                    strAvailable = "YES";
                } else {
                    strAvailable = "NO";
                }
                if (Display.isChecked()) {
                    strDisplay = "YES";
                } else {
                    strDisplay = "NO";
                }
                if (Demo.isChecked()) {
                    strDemo = "YES";
                    } else {
                        strDemo = "NO";
                    }
}
```

you can change it according to your need

Comment: i tried your approach. but i am getting only one id what i have defined in xml. but i have to fetch check boxes value on menu item select.
Problem is where and how can i get all check boxes reference.

Comment: yes i've told you you'll always get the only one id 
my app is working well and its best method to solve this problem tell me the approach what you are applying here to get i'll try my best to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Just use setTag(int) and getTag() method to set  id and get  id  of controls. like EditText,checkbox etc

Answer (score 1):

use

```
cb.setId(groupPosition+childPosition);
```

to set the ID and to retrieve use:

```
cb.getId();
```

group position+child position will give you the exact position of the item.

and in onClick you can get the ID you had set while creating the checkbox.

Comment: where should i add:
cb.setId(groupPosition+childPosition);

Comment: after you create the checkbox "CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );"

Comment: ok but in case group id is 1 and child id id 2
and group id is 2 and child is 1 
in thease cases it would be a conflict

Comment: yes. But in any case, why don't you take an array which saves the corresponding values like grp1 has 3 elements, grp 2 has 4 elements. So you number them from 1 to 7

Comment: actually i don't know how much group are there and how much child are there. because all data is dynamic.

Comment: oh. i am sorry then i don't think this solution will work for you.