# Buttons in ExpandableListView - unusual tag behaviour

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement an Android activity. It would be, basically, an ExpandableListActivity, except every "parent" row should have a button, which would add a new child to its group. When the button is clicked, I need to know to which parent row it belongs.

I am trying to use the tag in the buttons to store the number of its parent row, so when the button is clicked, I can simply use getTag().

The code for my custom adapter is the following (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015230/android-expandablelistview-parent-with-button)):

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(_context, R.layout.group_row, null);
        Button addButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_button);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("ExpListAdp", "Tag: " + view.getTag());
            }
        });
        addButton.setFocusable(false);
    }        

    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
    textView.setText(((HashMap)getGroup(groupPosition)).get("Group Item").toString()); 
    Button addButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_button);
    if(addButton.getTag() == null)  {
        addButton.setTag(Integer.valueOf(groupPosition));
        Log.d("ELA", "tag set to " + Integer.valueOf(groupPosition));
    }

    return convertView; 
}
```

This works fine until a group is expanded. At that moment, the value returned by the button click changes depending on which groups are expanded or collapsed. It is always one of the expectable values (that is, it always belongs to one of the buttons) - but it is rarely its own. E.g:

> Click 0: Logged "Tag:0" 
>   Click 1: Logged "Tag:1" 
>   Click 2: Logged "Tag:2" 
>   Click 3: Logged "Tag:3" 
>   Expand group 1 
>   Click 0: Logged "Tag:0" 
>   Click 1: Logged "Tag:1" 
>   Click 2: Logged **"Tag:3"** 
>   Click 3: Logged **"Tag:2"**

Tags are only being assigned once, and it happens even if the whole expanded list fits onscreen. So, is my code wrong somewhere? Or is there some sort of bug related to this, as they seem to suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633823/strange-behaviour-in-expandablelistview-android)?

I haven't pasted any more code so as not to make the post even longer - please let me know if you would like to see the xmls, the activity code, etc.

Comment: try to put addButton.setTag() inside the "if block" only. no need to check for if(addButton.getTag() == null) .

Comment: Thank you, but nope, it doesn't work :( The first version was just as you say, I only changed it to be sure tags were not being re-assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the views are being recycled? Even if the tag is non-null you should be setting it.

Moreover, you may not need the tag at all; why not include that information as part of the onClickListener?

```
final int buttonPos = groupPosition;
addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Log.i("On button click", "Position = %d", buttonPos);
        //stuff using buttonPos
    }
};
```

Comment: Well that was it - thank you very much! I had tried to set the tag always, but I did it in the if(convertView==null) block, which as you said, isn't enough in the case of recycling. For the sake of completion, your second idea does not work for me: the groupPosition that gets into the onClick holds the weird values, not the real ones. Anyway, accepting, and thanks again!